# azure policy - finding the existenceCondition value

Tags: azure-policy

I'm currently trying to understand the Azure policies.
I think I've got my head around the aliases, but I'm having trouble understanding where to find the correct values for existenceCondition equals field (example below)

```
  "existenceCondition": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Sql/transparentDataEncryption.status",
            "equals": "Enabled"
          },
```

Another example of this is Azure security center, the alias is `"Microsoft.Security/pricings/pricingTier"`
I guessed that the values would be `enabled, disabled,` but the correct values were

```
standard, free.
```

So where do I confirm what the aliases conditions should be set to?

Thanks
Russ

Answer (score 0):

With the new Azure Policy VS Code extension, you can see what your current resources are set to. However, the only way to see all the options would be to look up the documentation for the property.